# Remove the gap pattern from files

Tags: linux, python, perl, programming, bioinformatics

I want to remove gaps (-). if gap found continuous >10 in all >Tem at the same position then remove the all gaps and also remove the sequences or gap from the query at the same position which are in  Tem. 
Example
If gap in 1st template and not gap in 2nd template then not remove the gap.
Example of Input file

```
>Tem1.pdb
------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------GETLGEKWKKKLNQLSRKEFDLYKKSGI
TEVDRTEAKEGLKRGETT-HHAVSRGSAKLQWFVERNMVIPEGRVIDLGCGRGGWSYYCA
>Tem2.pdb
------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------GRTLGEQWKEKLNAMSREEFFKYRREAI
IEVDRTEARRARRENNIVGGHPVSRGSAKLRWLVEKGFVSPIGKVIDLGCGRGGWSYYAA
>Query_seq
PKFEKQLGQVMLLVLCAGQLLLMRTTWAFCEVLTLATGPILTLWEGNPGRFWNTTIAVST
ANIFRGSYLAGAGLAFSLIKNAQTPRRGTGTTGETLGEKWKRQLNSLDRKEFEEYKRSGI
LEVDRTEAKSALKDGSKI-KHAVSRGSSKIRWIVERGMVKPKGKVVDLGCGRGGWSYYMA
```

Out file should look like this

```
>Temp1
--------------------------------GETLGEKWKKKLNQLSRKEFDLYKKSGI
TEVDRTEAKEGLKRGETT-HHAVSRGSAKLQWFVERNMVIPEGRVIDLGCGRGGWSYYCA
>Temp2
--------------------------------GRTLGEQWKEKLNAMSREEFFKYRREAI
IEVDRTEARRARRENNIVGGHPVSRGSAKLRWLVEKGFVSPIGKVIDLGCGRGGWSYYAA
>Query_se
ANIFRGSYLAGAGLAFSLIKNAQTPRRGTGTTGETLGEKWKRQLNSLDRKEFEEYKRSGI
LEVDRTEAKSALKDGSKI-KHAVSRGSSKIRWIVERGMVKPKGKVVDLGCGRGGWSYYMA
```

Comment: post your current code showing your efforts

Comment: It might be better to ask this on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com, but be sure to post code showing what you've tried so far

Comment: Yes.. But Unable to get proper solution

Comment: 1) Why does `>Tem1.pdb` become `>Temp1` and the like? 2) Do you want to remove all lines consisting entirely of dashes? (--> `grep -vxe "-*"`) 3) What is the rule to remove the line after `>Query_seq`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Unix&Linux SE is not a script writing service.

Comment: 1) Not matter of >Tem1.pdb and > Temp1. 2) I want to remove the gaps(--) if gaps found in all Temp at same position. Gaps should be continues more than 10. 3) I also want to remove the gap from >Query. Because my objective is to keep equal number of words in all Temp and Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in python:

```
import re

tem1 = [ "------------------------------------------------------------",
    "--------------------------------GETLGEKWKKKLNQLSRKEFDLYKKSGI",
    "TEVDRTEAKEGLKRGETT-HHAVSRGSAKLQWFVERNMVIPEGRVIDLGCGRGGWSYYCA"
]

tem2 = [ "------------------------------------------------------------",
   "--------------------------------GRTLGEQWKEKLNAMSREEFFKYRREAI",
   "IEVDRTEARRARRENNIVGGHPVSRGSAKLRWLVEKGFVSPIGKVIDLGCGRGGWSYYAA"
]

query  = [ "PKFEKQLGQVMLLVLCAGQLLLMRTTWAFCEVLTLATGPILTLWEGNPGRFWNTTIAVST",
    "ANIFRGSYLAGAGLAFSLIKNAQTPRRGTGTTGETLGEKWKRQLNSLDRKEFEEYKRSGI",
    "LEVDRTEAKSALKDGSKI-KHAVSRGSSKIRWIVERGMVKPKGKVVDLGCGRGGWSYYMA"
]

for line in  range(2):
    if re.search("^-*$", tem1[line]) and re.search("^-*$", tem2[line]):
            tem1.pop(line)
            tem2.pop(line)
            query.pop(line)

print(tem1, tem2, query)
```

Now all you need to do is parse your input file and format your output file